# ORACLE: force like to use index?

Tags: oracle, select, query-optimization, sql-like

I have a table that has among others, two columns

```
SPONSOR_ID     number
NR_CERTIFICATE char(11)
```

And there's a index for these two columns

```
NR_CERTIFICATE + SPONSOR_ID
```

This table has hundreds of thousands of rows, and the problem is, when we filter by a specific certificate, the select takes nanoseconds as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_XXX WHERE NR_CERTIFICATE = '33300123456'
```

the problem is when we use LIKE to filter:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_XXX WHERE NR_CERTIFICATE LIKE '%123456'
```

Then the select takes around 15 seconds.

I know that in this case, the index is discarded and a table scan takes place. Is there a way to force ORACLE to use the index in this case? Or is there a way to speed up this select?

Answer (score 0):

You can "force" the index use with [optimizer hints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#i8327) :

```
SELECT /*+INDEX(TBL_XXX,YOUR_INDEX_NAME)*/ * 
FROM TBL_XXX 
WHERE NR_CERTIFICATE LIKE '%123456'
```

That answers the question but not sure if that will solve your issue. You should show the table struct  and explain plan for further help

Answer (score 0):

If you force the use of the index with an hint, Oracle will do a full index scan.
It will not be interesting for you.If your query has a sense, maybe your data model is not appropriate. Maybe a good way is to split you column nr_certificate in two columns. If it's possible, it will be easy to you after to have the good and quick query.